# libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394 UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, kurento

I have installed and configured kurento media server using,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

after restarting the server the error log says

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

And i am not able to share video stream with this,because the remote video does not shows.How to fix this?

**EDIT**

When i try to compile with  `sudo mvn clean compile exec:java`, I got errors
[image]

Comment: That error just tells you that you won't be able to use firewire media feeds directly connected to your KMS, as that library is not initialised. You can safely ignore that. You need to describe your setup, and do some debugging yourself in order to be able to get a useful answer.

Comment: @igracia fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection timed out. now this shows this error

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with kurento... Also, please describe when do you get that, as I'm quite confident you are not receiving that answer when starting the media server, but most likely when trying to get the code of a tutorial. Again, please describe your setup, or it will be quite hard to give you any guidance.

Comment: @igracia I updated my question with errors,could you help me?

Comment: Using this command `$netstat -ltnp` check kurento service is running. If yes. Then install npm,node,bower globally. Afterwords try this

`git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.2.0
mvn compile exec:java`

Comment: @SantoshShingare It is working,but i am using amazon ec2 instance.i cal view the web page ,but cant't view remote stream.do you know the reason?

Comment: @Shijin You need to configure a STUN server. Please read the project's [documentation](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers), as all this is there.